# What issue / series is this Batman comic panel from?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

While researching another question I came across this screenshot:

[image]

I'd like to know what issue# and / or series this is from.

Also, who are the other 4 charactes (other than Batman)? I think Robin is Damian Wayne, and that is Batwoman. Who is the other Batman and the person in the shadows?

Comment: can you provide a link to where you got this screen shot from

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The panel is from the Batman Incorporated series. The people are (left to right):

- Tim Drake (Red Robin) (in the shadows)
- Damian Wayne (Robin)
- Dick Grayson (Batman of Gotham City)
- Stephanie Brown (Batgirl)
- Bruce Wayne (CEO of Batman Inc.)

Comment: Do you know which issue #?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I would have to go digging through my comic boxes to find the exact issue. I just knew it when I saw it.

Comment: @Thaddeus - it's from "Batman: The Return #1". Link - http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_The_Return_Vol_1_1